# how to clear node custom field cache in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7. i changed the value of one custom field from the site, with a sql query, but 
when i trying to edit the node in the admin, the value of the field was the old one.
what can i do to fix this issue, without clearing the cache from the admin panel?

Comment: Looks like a caching issue, and you don't want to invalidate the cache.... hmm.... I'd say: just wait a day or two.

Comment: Can you paste the code how you are updating the field ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to clear cache after modification via `SQL` query:

```
 // Clear field cache
 cache_clear_all("field:node:$nid", 'cache_field');
```

Or for other entities

```
cache_clear_all("field:$entity_type:$entity->id", 'cache_field');
```

Comment: I ran into this [problem with privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/node/2577823#comment-10393949) and used this technique in hook_field_attach_insert() and it solved the issue for me.